# Behaviour of arguments/parameters and variables inside Shared Functions in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, function, shared

Well I am a new to VB.NET, converting a legacy system to .NET world. Recently I have been reviewing the already existing code since I joined the project quite late in the team.

So I find that there are many shared functions (not shared class) inside many classes. I doubt this may create some problem if two requests ( i.e two different HTTP request to the same method as it's a WCF application, of course exposed methods are not shared but internally called methods are shared) comes to the same shared method and both the calls to the method may have different method parameters/arguments, overwriting each other's arguments.

In short, if shared method has a list of arguments which is going to be processed, is there any chance of inconsistencies in the light of multiple access to the shared method via two http requests.

I would appreciate each and every response the thread.

Thanks,
JJ

Comment: Are these classes with the shared methods just helper classes and have no fields or properties of their own? If so, then it should be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Parameters are local to the method call and will not interact across threads.

However, if you use `Shared` fields or variables, you will have issues.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that parameters are local to the method call; however, that will not necessarily limit their reach. Class variables sent as ByVal parameters can still result in interactions across threads. You may want to read up on the `SyncLock` keyword. The use of the `Shared` keyword will not affect (i.e. reduce) the chances of such interactions.

The main issue about multithreaded applications is when the very same range of memory gets referenced by more than one thread at a time, particularly when any one of those threads may make memory writes.

---

Some things to think about:

(1) Visual Basic (and C#) dichotomizes variables (and data types) into two species: the "Value" (or "Structure"), and the "Reference" (or "Class").

(2) The "Value" data type means that a direct reference is made to an actual collection of bits that represents an Integer, or a Boolean, or even a bitmap, or some other kind of object. In old school parlance, this is the "image" of an instantiation of an object. It is the state space of the object. It is what makes an object itself versus being some other object, independant of where in memory it may be.

(3) The "Reference" data type means that this a very special Structure which somehow indicates the data type of the object and where in memory it resides. The computer will interpret a "Reference" to obtain the actual image of the object.

(4) When a "Value" parameter is passed ByVal, that means a new object is created that is in the identical image of the original expression being passed, and it is upon this copy that the function or method operates. The image of the original "Value" cannot be affected.

(5) When a "Value" parameter is passed ByRef, that means a new "Reference" variable is created, and that "Reference" variable will contain the information that will interpret back to the image of the original "Value". Now the image of the original "Value" can be changed.

(6) When a "Reference" parameter is passed ByVal, the very special Structure, which gets interpreted back to the actual image of the object, gets copied. It is upon this copy of the very special Structure that the function or method operates. This copy still points to the actual image of the object. Which means that an object of a Reference variable that is passed by ByVal can still have its image (i.e. its "Value") changed. However, the very special Structure of the original "Reference" itself cannot be changed.

(7) Note that the String type is an odd duck: It will behave as if it were a "Value" parameter even though it is in fact a "Reference" type. Hence a String passed ByVal will not be affected in the same way any other class would. Actually, String is an example of an immutable type - which means that steps are taken to prevent changes to the image of its "Value". (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383979.aspx and http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/01/13/immutable-types-understand-them-and-use-them/ for more details.)

(8) When a "Reference" parameter is passed ByRef, one now has created a new "Reference" object that points to the original "Reference" object (that, in turn, points to the "Value" of some other object). The use of ByRef on a "Reference" allows one to modify (or create anew) the very special Structure of the original "Reference" object being passed as a parameter. A function or method that performs a swap operation will use ByRef on "Reference" parameters.

(9) Some people say that a "Reference" is the same as a memory address. While in particular cases this may in fact be true, technically it is not. The very special Structure does not have to be a memory address in whatever image would be valid for the CPU - although utlimately the computer will translate it into a valid memory address at some point.

(10) The keyword `Me` is an automatic "Reference" to the object that is currently executing the class member. Under the hood, it exists as a parameter too, one that is sent unseen. EXCEPT in the case of a `Shared` member -  in which case `Me` is unavailable.